# Java dead code in different places

Tags: java, dead-code

Sorry if I ask a stupid question, long time no practice with Java......
I wrote some code to simulate the Hash Table.
Here is one function of my code:

```
protected int find(K key){
    int avail=-1;
    int i=hashValue(key);
    int j=i;
    do{
        Entry<K, V> element = bucket[i];

        if(element==null){
            if(avail<0){
                avail=i;
            }
            break;
        }

        if(key.equals(element.getK())){
            return i; // found
        }

        if(element==this.used){
            if(avail<0){
                avail=i;
            }
        }
        i=(i+1)%capa;
    }while(i!=j);
    return -(avail+1); // return a hash address
}
```

The strange thing is, when I change the if statement if(element==null) back a little bit (anywhere but the very beginning of the structure), it will then warn me it is a dead code:

```
protected int find(K key){
    int avail=-1;
    int i=hashValue(key);
    int j=i;
    do{
        Entry<K, V> element = bucket[i];

        if(key.equals(element.getK())){
            return i; // found
        }

        if(element==this.used){
            if(avail<0){
                avail=i;
            }
        }

        // dead code then
        if(element==null){
            if(avail<0){
                avail=i;
            }
            break;
        }
        //dead code then

        i=(i+1)%capa;
    }while(i!=j);
    return -(avail+1); // return a hash address
}
```

Anyone knows which part goes wrong?

Comment: Erwin's answer is spot-on, but just out of curiosity what is giving you the dead code feedback?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second code example, `element` can't possibly be `null` since you have already referenced it in the lines above: `element.getK()` in line

```
if(key.equals(element.getK()))
```

If it was `null` at that point, then you would have gotten a `NullPointerException` that you didn't catch. And that means that the method would not have continued to your `if(element == null)` statement.

If `element` is *not* `null`, then the body of your `if` statement won't be executed either.

Comment: Thanks a million. That should be the case. I should go and test with some data first, which the alarm will raise and I will know......